# How to get object from NSInvocationOperation called method?

Tags: ios, nsinvocationoperation

I have written code in my project

```
[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:self
                                        selector:@selector(loadImage)
                                        object:ob
```

in Method

```
- (void)loadImage {

}
```

Comment: If you want to get passed object i.e 'ob' in your case, your method 'loadImage' should accept argument like - (void)loadImage:(id) object.

Answer (score 1):

This might help;

```
// Your NSInvocationOperation definition 
[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadImage:) object:ob]; 

// Add an argument, this one is called 'sender'
- (void)loadImage:(id)sender { // 'sender' equals your object 'ob' from above
    // Do whatever you want to
}
```

For further refence / information about NSInvocationOperation:
[NSInvocationOperation Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSInvocationOperation_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: If you add a parameter to `loadImage:` then you need to update the `@selector` to `@selector(loadImage:)`. The colon is part of the method name.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it